# Compare data in bytes to a hex number

Tags: c, hex, byte

I need to read data from stdin where I need to check if 2 bytes are equal to 0x001 or 0x002 and then depending on the value execute one of two types of code. Here is what i tried:

```
uint16_t type;
uint16_t type1 = 0x0001;
while( ( read(0, &type, sizeof(type)) ) > 0 ) {
  if (type == type1) {
   //do smth
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what numeric system the read uses since printing the value of type both as decimal and as hex returns something completely different even when i wrtie 0001 on stdin

Comment: `read` reads raw bytes from its “file” (stream, whatever). When you type on a keyboard, the keystrokes are commonly transformed to ASCII characters. There are ways to type raw byte values as input, but you probably do not want to do that. Most likely, you want to read the ASCII characters into a buffer and examine them to see if they are digit characters. If so, they represent a numeral, and then you may want to convert that numeral (made of characters) into a number (perhaps stored in a `uint16_t`). There are various ways to do this, including standard C library routines and simple code…

Comment: … Which ways are appropriate for doing this depend on the course assignment you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

The characters 0x0001 and 0x0002 are control characters in UTF-8, you wont be able to type them manually.

If you are trying to compare the character input - use `gets` and `atoi` to convert the character-based input of `stdin` into an integer, or if you want to continue using read - compare against the characters `'0' '0' '0' '1'/'2'` instead of the values to get proper results

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what kind of OS you're using.  If you're using Unix or Linux or MacOS, at the command line, it can be pretty easy to rig up simple ways of testing this sort of program.  If you're using Windows, though, I'm sorry, my answer here is not going to be very useful.

(I'm also going to be making heavy use of the Unix/Linux
"pipe" concept, that is, the vertical bar `|` which sends the output of one program to the input of the next.  If you're not familiar with this concept, my answer may not make much sense at first.)

If it were me, after compiling your program to `a.out`, I would just run

```
echo 00 00  00 01  00 02 | unhex | a.out
```

In fact, I *did* compile your program to `a.out`, and tried this, and... it didn't work.  It didn't work because my machine (like yours) uses little-endian byte order, so what I should have done was

```
echo 00 00  01 00  02 00 | unhex | a.out
```

Now it works perfectly.

The only problem, as you've discovered if you tried it, is that `unhex` is not a standard program.  It's one of my own little utilities in my personal bin directory.  It's massively handy, and it's be super useful if something like it were standard, but it's not.  (There's probably a semistandard Linux utility for doing this sort of thing, but I don't know what it is.)

What is pretty standard, and you probably can use it, is a base-64 decoder.  The problem there is that there's no good way to hand-generate the input you need.  But I can generate it for you (using my unhexer).  If you can run

```
echo AAABAAIA | base64 -d | a.out
```

that will perform an equivalent test of your program.  `AAABAAIA` is the base-64 encoding of the three 16-bit little-endian words 0000 0001 and 0002, as you can see by running

```
echo AAABAAIA | base64 -d | od -h
```

On some systems, the `base64` command uses a `-D` option, rather than `-d`, to request decoding.  That is, if you get an error message like "invalid option -- d", you can try

```
echo AAABAAIA | base64 -D | a.out
```